# Using AJAX to popolate a tab with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, servlets

I want to modify this ajax request in such a way it populates a tab (dinamically) with a JSON that receives. NOW the ajax code prints only the object json that receives by a Servlet. This is the code in jquery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var form = $('#form1');

 form.submit(function () {
//event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
  type: form.attr('method'),
  url: form.attr('action'),
  data: form.serialize(),
 success: function (data) {
 var result=data;

  $('#result').html(result);
  // Result is a ID of a <div><div> in which I  
   //  print the json string. I want build a  
   // table here. But I want that this table is dinamic,   
   // that is also the NAME of columns must depends from json                                                             
  console.log(result);
     }
  });
  return false;
});  </script>
```

Instead, this is my servlet

```
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        String k = request.getParameter("choose"); 

        //From a dropdown select, for example I choose to print
        // the table "products"
         if(k.equals("products")){  
        ArrayList<Products> list = new ArrayList<Products>();
         list =  bDBean.listProducs();

         Iterator<Products> i = list.iterator();
                while(i.hasNext()){
                Products temp = i.next();
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create();
                String json = gson.toJson(temp);
               // response.setContentType("application/json");
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.getWriter().write(json);
                }
            }
          }
```

Comment: you are returning multiple json strings right now,why?

Comment: They are the objects that I want to place in a table

Comment: how does the response look like??

Comment: Every object has this form = {"productNo":1, "name":"Cheese","price":5.99}...etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First wrap your javascript code in a document ready statement

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(function() {
        var form = $('#form1');

        form.submit(function() {
          //event.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
              var table = '<table><thead><tr><td>productNo</td><td>name</td><td>price</td></tr></thead><tbody>'
              $.each(JSON.parse("["+data.split('}{').join('},{')+"]"), function(i, v) {
                table += '<tr><td>' + v.productNo + '</td><td>' + v.name +' < /td><td>'+v.price+'</td > < /tr>';
              });
              table += '</tbody></table>'
              $('#result').html(table);
            }
          });
          return false;
        });
      });

    </script>
```

use the following success function to display your table

```
success: function (data) {
var table = '<table><thead><tr><td>productNo</td><td>name</td><td>price</td></tr></thead><tbody>'
$.each(JSON.parse("["+data.split('}{').join('},{')+"]"),function(i,v){
      table+= '<tr><td>'+v.productNo+'</td><td>'+v.name+'</td><td>'+v.price+'</td></tr>';
});
table+='</tbody></table>'
$('#result').html(table);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. It refreshes the page sending me to servlet page. And it prints  {"productNo":1, "name":"Cheese","price":5.99}...etc.
Debugging I discovered that it doesn't enter in success: function(data)

Comment: Same problem. It isn't changed anything

Comment: Could you be more clear? Sorry, but it a newbie :/ . 
Anyway it seems that that the script is never activated

Comment: your javascript code needs to run after the page is loaded this is why you need a document ready statement

Comment: it doesn't work. Anyway the variables "form" is not coloured. Usual in Netbeans is violet. It's frustrating..:(

Comment: Anyway there are warnings in the code  ' Expected semicolon ; after "" ' .
Can be a problem?

Comment: No, I tried to insert console.lo("test" ) in the script...but they are not printed

Comment: do you know where the console is ??

Comment: I have this error in console Unexpected string to line --> table+= '<tr><td>'+v.productNo+'</td><td>'+v.name+v</td><td>'+v.price+'</td></tr>';

Comment: Infinite problems..now I have Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '355' in {"productNo":1,"name":"cheese","price":9.99}..etc...

Comment: did you create a array of the objects in java and display it to the page? the response from the server should look like: `[{"productNo":1,"name":"cheese","price":9.99},{},{}...]`

Comment: the response is : {"productNo":1,"name":"cheese","price":9.99},{},{}  ...without   " [  ]  "

Comment: i have updated my answer to create the script based on your output

Comment: WOOOOW IT WORKS! but the last problem it's that prints in bad way the table

Answer (score 1):

The Uncaught TypeError could be beacsue your not parsning your json
Like `$.each(JSON.parse(myData), ...);`

Comment: I resolved in this way   $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i, v) { ....
but the table is not print

Comment: I receive this :  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON

Comment: what does the data variable look like before you try JSON.parse?

Comment: objects like this {"productNo":1,"name":"cheese","price":9.99}

Comment: maybe your data is already and object and doesnt need parsing, just try one thing data[0] in like console.log and see what you get.

Comment: I tried console.log(data[0])  FIRTS the $each and prints --> " {  " . Then I put console.log(data[0]) IN $ $each and I receive jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '355' in {"productNo":1,"name":"Formaggio","price":9.99

Comment: $.each(data, function() {
  $.each(json.parse(data), function(i, v) {
    consol.log(v. productNo)
  });
});

Comment: i wrote a comment above this that contains a loop around the original loop

Comment: should I  copy and paste only ?

Comment: No just add the loop $.each(data, function() {  }); around the original